# Navigation Bar Item not clickable when UITextView resigns first responder

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add clickable buttons to the right of the navigation bar. The button can be clicked when a `UITextView` is active (i.e. when keyboard is present), **but is no longer clickable** once the keyboard is dismissed. The code is:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textview: UITextView!
    let buttonDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(didClickDone))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonDone
        self.textview.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func didClickDone() {
        print("Clicked on Done")
        self.textview.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

So when the `UITextView` is the first responder, clicking that "Done" button **does** print a message, and dismisses the keyboard.

After that, no matter how many times I click the "Done" button, the message is not printed. Any input is highly appreciated!

---

Additional information:

This `DetailViewController` has a list View Controller embedded in a navigation view controller, as such:

[image]

Below is the layout logic of the `DetailViewController`

[image]

The list View Controller has gesture recognizer enabled. Not sure if it has anything to do with this... The gesture recognizer is only set up for long-press.

---

UPDATE 1: I have removed the `textview.becomeFirstResponder()` line in the `ViewDidLoad()` method. When I enter the view, the keyboard does not show up, as expected. At this state, clicking on the button does not print a message...

Therefore I don't think it's the fault of `resignFirstResponder()`...

UPDATE 2: I have changed `target: nil` to `target: self`  but it's no use...

But thanks for all the replies! Any further help is appreciated...

Comment: This code seems fine. may be other piece of code affecting this.

Comment: Set target: Self instead of nil for UIBarButtonItem

Comment: as per the code inside `didClickDone ` method it should dismiss the keyboard when its . Please tell us what you want to when you click done button once again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `viewDidLoad`, create `UIBarButtonItem` and assign it there instead of declaring it as class member.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didClickDone))
    self.textview.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Wow OK that worked! Thanks!!   Can I declare the variable and later initialize it within `viewDidLoad()`? Is it because the initialization happened before `viewDidLoad()` that it breaks?

Comment: Exactly. If you need reference for barItem, then you can assign it inside `viewDidLoad` or you can create as `lazy` variable. Either way will work.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code as below

```
let buttonDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didClickDone))

@@IBAction func didClickDone(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Clicked on Done")
    self.textview.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```